# r conditional drop rows by Group

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

This is my dataset:

```
   Group     Status      From    To
   Blue      No          1994    2000
   Red       No          1994    1997
   Red       Yes         1998    2002
   Yellow    No          1994    2014
   Yellow    Yes         2015    2021
   Purple    No          1994    1997
```

I like to get rid of the rows with `Status=No` only where they belong to a Group that repeats more than once.

For instance. Group=Red and Yellow have 2 rows, I like to get rid of the row with Status=No within these two groups. The final dataset like this.

```
   Group     Status      From    To
   Blue      No          1994    2000
   Red       Yes         1998    2002
   Yellow    Yes         2015    2021
   Purple    No          1994    1997
```

Any suggestions regarding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return rows with `Status = 'Yes'` if number of rows in the group is greater than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(if(n() > 1) Status == 'Yes' else TRUE) %>%
  ungroup

#  Group  Status  From    To
#  <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>
#1 Blue   No      1994  2000
#2 Red    Yes     1998  2002
#3 Yellow Yes     2015  2021
#4 Purple No      1994  1997
```

For this data, since `'Yes' > 'No'` we can also do -

```
df %>%
  arrange(Group, desc(Status)) %>%
  distinct(Group, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("Blue", "Red", "Red", "Yellow", "Yellow", 
"Purple"), Status = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), 
    From = c(1994L, 1994L, 1998L, 1994L, 2015L, 1994L), To = c(2000L, 
    1997L, 2002L, 2014L, 2021L, 1997L)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```